# Store User Credit Information

Tags: ios, objective-c, braintree

I have followed up the `BrainTree` tutorial for objective-c and ended up the following implementation. I wonder, how could I able to store user credit card information such as `Uber` or `AirBnb`. Everytime, user clicks on make a payment, and displays the credit card information entry viewcontroller.

By the way, transaction happens succesfully, and I could able to see charges on my `BrainTree` sandbox account.

```
- (IBAction)placeOrderBtnClicked:(id)sender {    
    [self showDropIn: TOKEN];
}

- (void)showDropIn:(NSString *)clientTokenOrTokenizationKey {
    BTDropInRequest *request = [[BTDropInRequest alloc] init];
    BTDropInController *dropIn = [[BTDropInController alloc] initWithAuthorization:clientTokenOrTokenizationKey request:request handler:^(BTDropInController * _Nonnull controller, BTDropInResult * _Nullable result, NSError * _Nullable error) {

        if (error != nil) {
            NSLog(@"ERROR");
        } else if (result.cancelled) {
            NSLog(@"CANCELLED");
            [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
        } else {
            [self postNonceToServer:result.paymentMethod.nonce];
        }
    }];
    [self presentViewController:dropIn animated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)postNonceToServer:(NSString *)paymentMethodNonce {
        self.manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
        NSDictionary *params = @{@"amount" : @"44", @"payment_method_nonce" : paymentMethodNonce};
        manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
        [manager POST:URLString parameters:params progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull operation, id  _Nonnull responseObject) {
            NSLog (@"transaction is succesfull");
        } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable operation, NSError * _Nonnull error) {

        }];
    }

// the following method never gets called!!!
- (void)fetchExistingPaymentMethod:(NSString *)clientToken {
    [BTDropInResult fetchDropInResultForAuthorization:clientToken handler:^(BTDropInResult * _Nullable result, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if (error != nil) {
            NSLog(@"ERROR");
        } else {
            // Use the BTDropInResult properties to update your UI
            NSLog(@"Payment method :%@", result.paymentMethod);
            NSLog(@"Payment Description :%@", result.paymentDescription);
            NSLog(@"Payment option type :%ld", (long)result.paymentOptionType);
        }
    }];
}
```

**UPDATE:** I want to see the following highlighted section

[image]

Answer (score 1):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact [support](https://articles.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

Do you mean that you want the payment form to display the stored payments or are you asking how to store the payments? In order to have the Drop-in display previously stored payment methods, you need to pass the customer_id into the [ClientToken.generate()](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/client-token/generate/) call on your server-side.  If you are looking to save a payment method, then again, this would happen on your server-side call, as you would have to pass the nonce from client to server and use that nonce in a [PaymentMethod.create()](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/payment-method/create) call.

Comment: For what you want above, you need to follow the links in my comment above to display previously stored payment methods. This UI is created from passing the `customer_id` into the ClientToken.generate() call on the server side. It is not code you write on the front-end. It will only display this if that customer has stored payment methods. Therefore, you also need to have the PaymentMethod.create() call as mentioned above.